# Creating UWP app package results in errors

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

When I attempt to create a release UWP package for side loading I get the following error :-

> 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5):
>   error : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5):
>   error :    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterCodeGen.FindXmlnsIndex(MemberMapping[]
>   members) 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5):
>   error :    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterCodeGen.WriteStructMethod(StructMapping
>   mapping) 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5):
>   error :    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterCodeGen.GenerateMethod(TypeMapping
>   mapping) 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5):
>   error :    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationCodeGen.GenerateReferencedMethods()
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5):
>   error :    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterCodeGen.GenerateEnd()
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5):
>   error :    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(XmlMapping[]
>   xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence,
>   XmlSerializerCompilerParameters parameters, Hashtable assemblies,
>   String outputDir, IEnumerable`1 referenceDirectories, String
>   intermediateDir, Boolean loadAssembly) 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5):
>   error :    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer(Type[]
>   types, XmlMapping[] mappings, CompilerParameters parameters, String
>   outputDir, IEnumerable`1 referenceDirectories, String intermediateDir,
>   Boolean loadAssembly) 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5):
>   error :    at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateSerializer(Type[]
>   types, String outputDir, IEnumerable`1 referenceDirectories, String
>   intermediateDir, List`1 wcfSerializers, Boolean loadAssembly)
>   1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5):
>   error :    at SerializationAssemblyGenerator.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x64\ilc\IlcInternals.targets(936,5):
>   error : Internal compiler error: One or more errors occurred.

My .appxmanifest file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">
  <Identity Name="XXXXXXXXXX" Publisher="XXXXXXXXXX" Version="1.0.4.0" />
  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="XXXXXXXXXX" PhonePublisherId="XXXXXXXXXX" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>XXXXXXXXXX</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>XXXXXXXXXX</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="XXXXXXXXXX.App">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="XXXXXXXXXX" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png" Description="XXXXXXXXXX" BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png">
        </uap:DefaultTile>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <uap:Capability Name="phoneCall" />
    <uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary" />
    <uap:Capability Name="userAccountInformation" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="location" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="proximity" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Does anyone have any ideas why this happens?

Comment: Including info from your Package.appxmanifest file especially the packaging tab will be helpful. Also, can you create a package for distribution outside Windows store?

Comment: I managed to create a Debug package however this then prompted for installation of other packages upon installation. I am looking to create a package which I can distribute outside of the Windows store as it is a LOB app. Is it possible to create an installer or similar like in the good old days of Win32 apps?

Comment: Curious. It always creates a APPXBUNDLE file which is basically an installer for me when I create a Package to distribute outside the store and adds the Dependency Packages to the product in a separate folder. I am looking around for your specific issue, so far no luck. Could you share info from your appxmanifest? If something is wrong, I think it's gotta be there

Comment: Yes I can share info from the appxmanifest. What would you like me to share?

Comment: The Declarations, Capabilities and Packaging tabs are what would most likely have an impact on packaging.

Comment: I have uploaded the appxmanifest file here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/5xk6lkm7hjfugah/Package.appxmanifest?dl=0. I have had a look and there doesn't seem to be anything specific I am doing. Am I even along the right tracks in being about to provide side loaded apps to third parties, without going through the Windows store?

Comment: I looked over at your file and It seems fine. [Have you gone through the UWP guide for packaging?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps)

Comment: You can't generate a single .exe for the app at UWP like old days. When you got this erros? When generating the package? Or executing the powershell script for installation?